# Why does my ODBC SelectCommand get truncated when I add a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, odbc

I am using an ODBC connection to retrieve a data set in C#. I can see that the full command string is added to the connection when it is created.

```
OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(GetCommandString(), odbcConnection);
```

I am using the following line to add the parameter to the command string.

```
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Foo", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = foo2;
```

However, when using SQL Profiler I can see that only a portion of the command string actually makes it to SQL.

During testing we have seen that the full string will get passed in if we hard code a value into the string and remove the parameter line shown above.

Does using a parameter restrict the length of the string that I can pass though?

Edited - Adding info about SQL query: Here is an example of what the query looks like before the parameter is added.

```
DECLARE @foo decimal
SET @foo = ?
Select c1,c2,c3,c4 from table1 where id = @foo
Select b1,b2,b3,b4 from table1 where id = @foo
Select a1,a2,a3,a4 from table1 where id = @foo
Select t1,t2,t3,t4 from table1 where id = @foo
```

Comment: Is this a question about the code failing with parameters or just not being able to see the full query text in SQL Profiler?

Comment: what type of database are you connecting to with your ODBC Connection?  And as stated by another, the @foo may not be allowed as a named parameter as may be available in other connections like SQLAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Is "@Foo" the right syntax for parameters using the OdbcCommand?  ODBC treats parameters differently than ADO.NET.  In ODBC, parameters are bound by position and all parameters use the placeholder '?' in the statement.

I'm not sure if OdbcCommand does some translation between named and positional parameters.  Maybe it does, and it's failing to rebuild the command successfully.

Also, if you are only connecting to SQL Server consider just using SqlClient.

Comment: I am pretty sure that @Foo is correct I have used similar syntax previously while working with this project. I posted an example of what the query looks like above. I'll try to look into how the query is being rebuilt. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting [scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.scale(VS.80).aspx) and precision?

And what do you mean by truncate? Do you get this...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE decCol = 123
```

when you expect

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE decCol = 123.456
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE decCol = 123.456 AND OtherCol = 'bar'
```

Also, profiler will capture the whole query text. Which leads me to ask, if you can use SQL profiler why are you using ODBC?

Comment: Closer to the 2nd example you listed. I am expecting to see around 20 select statements come through, but only 5 are coming through. And yes ODBC is probably not the optimal solution. Unfortunately the project is really constrained to its use based on the clients existing set up.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shown it looks like you're on the right track, but `"@Foo"`is probably the wrong syntax, but I can't say without seeing the actual output from `GetCommandString()`. The ODBC syntax is:

```
int foo2 = 5;
OdbcDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Bar WHERE Foo = ?", odbcConnection);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("Foo", OdbcType.Decimal).Value = foo2;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxdcah9t.aspx

Comment: I posted an example of the query above. I am fairly certain that the @Foo syntax is correct. I have used an odbc parameter in a similar fashion previously.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, that the @Foo syntax may not be correct. If your OdbcDriver understands @Foo as a parameter it won't be heeding its name and this may be leading you to write queries in a broken way.. Suppose this time youre trying to reuse a parameter (your other "working" queries do not feature this requirement)

SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = @Foo or col2 = @Foo

In Odbc will either not work or silently become equivalent to:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = ? or col2 = ?

You'll have to add parameter values for both params, you cannot just add one parameter called "@Foo" and have Odbc reuse the value.. Further, it matters not what your parameters are called, only that you add them in the right order:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("col1Val", "foo")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("column two value", "foo")
```

The name you give to parameters is solely a convenience for your reuse of them; the driver cares not what they are called

Switch to ? syntax and see if your issue persists